# Migrating 2003 Server to New Hardware

Tags: windows-server-2003, migration

I'm in the process of Migrating a Server 2003 installation to a completely new server with different hardware. I want the process to go smooth but am not sure where to start. So a few questions.

Is it possible to make an image of the existing server installation and then clone this image to the new server?

Does Microsoft provide any tools to help with this process.

And...can I use the same product key to activate the new installation once I install on the new server and do away with the old one?

Thank You. I know this question has been asked many times before but the answers seemed to be spotty at best and did not explain any of the caveats to the various methods of migration

Answer (score 1):

Q: Is it possible to make an image of the existing server installation and then clone this image to the new server?

A: With the right tools, maybe. Take a look at what Acronis has to offer.

Q: Does Microsoft provide any tools to help with this process?

A: Not for cloning the server but they have various tools for migrating shares, printers, etc.

Q: Can I use the same product key to activate the new installation once I install on the new server and do away with the old one?

A: Possibly. If the product key is an OEM key that came with the server with Windows pre-installed then it is NOT transferable to the new server. Otherwise, you should have no problem with activating the new server with your existing product key.

Comment: I've seen alot of threads where admins have cloned the existing installation over to new hardware but it is my understanding that this would fail because of incompatible drivers. Is there a workaround for that I am not noticing?

Comment: Yes there is. There are a number of tools/applications that can deal with bare metal restores/cloning to dissimmilar hardware. Acronis is just one of them. Check it out at their web site. www.acronis.com